# Exporting variable for noninteractive, nonlogin shell on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have the situation where I want to run a `bashrc` file on an OSX machine every time a shell is opened.

In this case, there is no login shell, and the shell is noninteractive. I've tried `~/.profile` `~/.bash_profile`. According to http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_63.html, I need to do `export BASH_ENV=/etc/bashrc`, but I don't know the bottom-most bash instance where I can export this.

Comment: If you want `BASH_ENV` to be set in every shell, you need to modify system environment variables from `launchd`. Read `man 5 launchd.plist` (in particular, `EnvironmentVariables`).

Comment: How are you opening the shell? OS X terminal emulators open login shells by default because the terminal emulator itself isn't started from a login shell.